# android pop up menu

Tags: android

I have followed this [tutorial](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/03/15/tutorial-1-transparent-panel-linear-layout-on-mapview-google-map/) to create a seek bar on a transparent background. How can I make it pop up on the screen when pressing a button ?

Comment: You need to add a button to your app and then call `button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){/*your code here*/});` In the OnClickListener, write some code that either adds the seek bar to the screen or sets its visibility from `View.GONE` to `View.VISIBLE`.

Comment: Do I have to create it programmatically or can I just load it from the xml file?

Comment: @plowman - +1, this should be answer not a comment.

Comment: @Radek I moved my comment to an answer to make it a little clearer. In Android, you can always choose to either inflate the Button from XML or create it entirely in Java. Let me know if you're unsure how to proceed and I can point you to some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a button to your app and then use that to set the visibility of the seek bar from `View.GONE` to `View.VISIBLE`. Something like this:

```
final TransparentPanel transparentPanel = ... //however you initialize
transparentPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE); //make it invisible to start
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    //Make the panel visible whenever someone clicks on your new button
    transparentPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
});

//add the button to whatever ViewGroup transparentPanel lives in
```